# Php Admin Application with forms

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello stackoverflow people,
For the last **Two days** ive been trying to create this **Staff applying system**
but i'm not to great at PHP and still learning but what i want it to do is they fill the forms out then click Submit then that downloads to a folder on the server With dated file names for each application for me to look over but i cant figure it out... My PHP only goes so far.. Is this system possible? can you make it for me or help me out?? Thanks alot for reading! :)

### Image

[Clarified Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MCsi.png)

```html
<?php
$tasktitle = $_POST['app'];
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI"); 
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki");
$date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%A");
$timesaved = strftime("%H:%M:%S");
$elapsedtime = $_POST['current_time'];
$file = "apps/".$date.".txt";
$cont = 'time finished: '.$timesaved.' - time elapsed: '.$elapsedtime.' - task name: '.$tasktitle.''. "n"; 

$f = fopen ($file, 'a+');
fwrite($f, $cont);
fclose($f);
?>
```

But it just writes a date in the file lol

Comment: Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Please be sure to use sentences, explain what you have tried, and actually ask a clear question. It's impossible to tell what you are asking right now, other than (1) is it possible and (2) can anyone help me? The answers are (1) yes and (2) no, not unless you narrow this down.

Comment: done added a image to show you what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a example where Post data is stored in a Dated text file line by line.

```
<form  method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="ign" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['ign'])) {
    $data = $_POST['name'] . '-' . $_POST['ign'] . "\n";
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $ret = file_put_contents('apps/'.$date.'.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you want to create a new file for every entry with dated filename use this code -

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['ign'])) {
    $data = $_POST['name'] . '-' . $_POST['ign'] . "\n";
    $i = 1;
    $new_file_name = date('Y-m-d');
    while (file_exists('apps/' . $new_file_name . '.txt')) {
        $new_file_name = (string) $new_file_name . '_' . $i;
        $i++;
    }
    $ret = file_put_contents('apps/' . $new_file_name . '.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if ($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    } else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me the "there was a problem writing this file"

Comment: @BrandonAnderson, where are you kept the php code? see "$ret = file_put_contents('apps/'.$date.'.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);". It will try to write to "apps" folder. If there is no app folder or the app folder doesn't have write permission, same error will be displayed.

Comment: Ahh okay i just needed to chmod it to 777 forgot lol but is there any way to make a new file everytime a new one comes in?

Comment: @BrandonAnderson, I edited and added a solution for dated new file with each entry.